# Cannot get Xna to work with visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

I am learning C# and I am trying to download xna 4.0, but the installer is preventing me from installing the software and says this is because i dont have the 2010 edition of visual studio express and will not work with the 2012 express version.

When i try to get 2010 from microsoft it redirects me to the 2013 express edition and does not allow me to download what i want.

Does anybody know what is the bet way to resolve this?

Comment: Try [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2010-express)

Comment: [XNA is dead](http://www.wpcentral.com/xna-dead-long-live-xna). Use [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I am working from a book which uses xna will this matter?

Comment: it *could* matter, this is why I didn't suggest it

Comment: It's an open source imlementation, there may be slight differences with the syntax

Answer (score 0):

http://ryan-lange.com/xna-game-studio-4-0-visual-studio-2012/
Worked perfectly fine twice for me.